# MongoDB Query for Records Where Value Occurs N Times or More

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

What MongoDB query would return the `Team` records where a city occurs at least twice in the collection and they are active?

If you can only answer the first part that helps too. (Returning the records where the city occurs at least twice)

Teams

```
[
  {teamName: 'Red', city: 'Altanta', active: false},
  {teamName: 'Blue', city: 'NYC', active: true},
  {teamName:'Yellow', city: 'NYC', active: false},
  {teamName:'Green', city: 'NYC', active: true},
  {teamName:'Gray', city: 'Atlanta', active: false},
  {teamName:'Purple', city: 'Atlanta', active: true},
  {teamName:'Black', city: 'Boston', active: false},
  {teamName:'Brown', city: 'Boston', active: true},
  {teamName:'Silver', city: 'Miami', active: false},
  {teamName:'White', city: 'Austin', active: true},
  {teamName:'Gold', city: 'Detroit', active: true},
]
```

The query would return:

```
[
  {teamName: 'Blue', city: 'NYC', active: true},
  {teamName:'Green', city: 'NYC', active: true},
  {teamName:'Purple', city: 'Atlanta', active: true},
  {teamName:'Brown', city: 'Boston', active: true},
]
```

Comment: Do you've to first check for `active:true` or first get documents where city is repeated & then check for active ? Cause if we check for active at first then you would not see  `Atlanta ` & `Boston`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

**Query 1 :**

```
Teams.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: '$city', count: { $sum: 1 }, data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
{ $match: { count: { $gte: 2 } } },
// Will project data where docs has active:true & data will be [] if none are active
{
    $project: {
        data: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$data',
                as: "item",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$item.active", true] }
            }
        }
    }
},
// Will remove docs where city is repeated but all documents has active:false
{ $match: { data: { $ne: [] } } }])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "NYC",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e156407c952870d7dfbb227"),
            "teamName" : "Blue",
            "city" : "NYC",
            "active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e156407c952870d7dfbb229"),
            "teamName" : "Green",
            "city" : "NYC",
            "active" : true
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "Atlanta",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e156407c952870d7dfbb22b"),
            "teamName" : "Purple",
            "city" : "Atlanta",
            "active" : true
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "Boston",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e156407c952870d7dfbb22d"),
            "teamName" : "Brown",
            "city" : "Boston",
            "active" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query 2 :**

```
Teams.aggregate([
    { $match: { active: true } },
    { $group: { _id: '$city', count: { $sum: 1 }, data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
    { $match: { count: { $gte: 2 } } }, { $project: { count: 0 } }])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "NYC",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e156407c952870d7dfbb227"),
            "teamName" : "Blue",
            "city" : "NYC",
            "active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e156407c952870d7dfbb229"),
            "teamName" : "Green",
            "city" : "NYC",
            "active" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Difference between `Query1` & `Query2` would be as in 2nd query you're filtering out `active:false` then there will be lesser documents & thereby cities getting repeated will also be effected as there are only fewer documents (you can see in `query1` result `Atlanta` & `Boston` appear in result though they have single document in `data`).